# How do I print two variables simultaneously using a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I want to print out the values of lists a and b in the following format:

```
a[0]
b[0]
a[1]
b[1]
```

...

I used this

```
for element, link in a, b:
    print(element)
    print(link.get('href'))
```

(sorry for post formatting, I don't understand why stackoverflow doesnt let me post with the code fences)

but it really doesn't work, what can I do to get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` for this.

```
for element, link in zip(a, b):
    print(element)
    print(link.get('href')
```